# How to merge two running Docker Containers?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

the scenario is if, in a team we are using an image to make docker containers. At some point i want to integrate the updates done by my team mate in my running containers , for example change of Apache version. Is there a way to do it??

Comment: Your best course of actions is probably to generate images from `Dockerfiles` and never modify the running containers.  This way, "merging changes" just means "merging the contents of your Dockerfiles", which is easy.

Comment: Thanks @larsks . I think its helpful. will use that approach. However my only concern is , say i have some data associated with a container. Probably it will get lost. Thats the reason I was searching for- how do I merge "running" containers.

Comment: Data should be separate from the container, either via a host volume or using `--volumes-from` and a data-only container.